# Clarification of TensorFlow's dynamic_decode sample_ids

Tags: tensorflow

`tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq`'s `dynamic_decode` returns three values, the first of which is a 2-tuple with named fields `'rnn_output'` and `sample_id`. I'm trying to understand what `sample_id` is, but I can't find any examples or documentation and the [example](https://youtu.be/RIR_-Xlbp7s?t=30m5s) at the TensorFlow Developer's Summit doesn't add much information. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample_id is the argmax of the rnn output

Answer (score 1):

```
rnn_output=[batch_size, max length of a sentence, probability of each word in a vocabulary]
sample_id = [batch_size, max length of a sentence]
```

For example:

```
batch_size is 99 
max length of a sentence is 15
Vocabulary size is 233
```

---

```
rnn_output = [99,15,233]
sample_id = [99,15]
```

As also mentioned above, sample_id second dimension contains the argmax value of the third dimension of `rnn_output`.

In a simpler language, `sample_id` second dimension will have the `rnn_output` third `dimension->max value->index`.